# How do I use jQuery in Svelte

Tags: jquery, svelte, sapper

Doing this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Shows the error

```
The $ prefix is reserved, and cannot be used for variable and import names svelte(illegal-declaration)
```

Comment: You can also `import jQuery from "jquery"` to avoid using the $ shorthand, which is indeed a reserved word in svelte. More generally, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338411/how-to-import-jquery-using-es6-syntax for methods to import jQuery using ES6 syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I figured but what I am trying to do is use a bootstrap component but the problem I am having now is the script runs before the component is mounted so at that point there is no element with the ID I am targeting

Comment: Thanks, I figured but what I am trying to do is use a bootstrap component but the problem I am having now is the script runs before the component is mounted so at that point there is no element with the ID I am targeting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57828618/10679649

Comment: @AneriEmmax to address your other issue (component not mounted) you can use svelte's `onMount` lifecycle method. See the official doc here: https://svelte.dev/docs#onMount

Comment: Solution for [SvelteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71017937/importing-jquery-in-sveltekit/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can just use `import as` syntax:

```
import * as $j from 'jquery';
```

Or as `anyName`  that you can use

Comment: Eslint says variable name start with `$` is reserved, thus can't start with `$`, so maybe use `j$`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Iirc it was due to a rollup error saying that $ is reserved. See [my anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73852993/12206312) if you're experiencing the same

Comment: It doesn't work for me too and I am using SvelteKit with Jquery-based UI framework

Answer (score 14):

I noticed that if JQuery is already available globally, then you can access it via `window.$` instead of just `$` and the svelte compiler won't complain.

Comment: Doing something like `const jq = window.$;` saves a few keystrokes

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery'
```

[relevant SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3291916/12206312)