# Importing jQuery in SvelteKit

Tags: jquery, svelte, sveltekit

How do I import jQuery in SvelteKit (with TypeScript support)?

`const jq = window.$` as one would do in Svelte runs into `window is not defined`.

**Update as of Aug 2022:** No longer running into `window is not defined`. See selected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make jQuery available globally. So in `app.html`:

```html
<!-- Example. Update to latest jQuery versions. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then in `.svelte` files, access jQuery via `window.$`:

```js
import { onMount } form 'svelte';
const jq = window.$;

onMount(() => {
  // Use jQuery as you wish. For example:
  jq(`#draggable-div`).draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use import as syntax:

```
import * as $jq from 'jquery';
```

Or you can do like this

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import js from 'jquery';

onMount(() => {
  window.jq = js;
});
```