# DateTimepicker bootstrap with sveltekit

Tags: bootstrap-5, sveltekit, bootstrap-datetimepicker, svelte-3

i want to write this code with svelte framework

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row"> 
  <div class='col-sm-6'> 
  <div class="form-group"> 
   <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'> 
     <input type='text' class="form-control" /> 
     <span class="input-group-addon"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span> 
  </div> 
</div> 
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function () { $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(); }); 

</script> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Or if there is another way to write the timing as in the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07ZTY.png)

I searched for a long time and didn't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're using jQuery in svelte, **do note** that the `$` shorthand is a reserved word in svelte and this won't work.
Please visit this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58219453/how-do-i-use-jquery-in-svelte) to see how to use jQuery and Svelte together... Otherwise you could use the [vanillajs-datepicker](https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/) library to implement the date picker in your svelte web app.
See my demo of the library [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/6a7025c9bc864364b3adaa40024c26f7?version=3.55.0). Do read the comments for more guidance
**Happy Coding  ....**

Comment: thanks for your answer,
can you tell me, how can i add the timepicker on the vanilajs-datepicker in svelte App